# If a firebase rule checks resource values, will it always give permission denied when the document does not exist?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was writing a rule for my "users" collection that looks like this:

```
    match /users/{userId} {

      // Returns true if auth's email is empty and user's 
      // insensitiveEmail is empty or non-existent
      function emailDoesNotExist(resource) {
        return request.auth.token.email.size() == 0 && 
        (!fieldExists(resource, "insensitiveEmail") || resource.data.insensitiveEmail.size() == 0);
      }
    
      // Returns true if auth's email matches user's email
      function emailMatches(resource) {
          return request.auth.token.email == resource.data.insensitiveEmail;
      }
    
      // Returns true if the auth uid matches the resource's uid 
      function uidMatchesResource(resource) {
          return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid && request.auth.uid == resource.id;
      }

      allow get: if request.auth != null
        && request.auth.uid == userId
        && uidMatchesResource(resource)
        && (emailDoesNotExist(resource) || emailMatches(resource))
```

I'm getting `[firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.` errors in a case where the user id being requested does not exist in the database.

Is that because I'm trying to do comparisons against `resource` and `resource` doesn't exist?

And if that's so, is there a way I can validate data in returned documents without preventing requests that result in 0 returned documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow your query to access documents that don't exist, perform a `null` check against `resource` and short-circuit the result before the other checks are resolved.

Additionally, your email check can be greatly simplified with the use of [`Map#get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get).

```js
match /users/{userId} {
  // ...

  // Returns true if auth's email matches the stored
  // insensitiveEmail value (if any).
  // - has an email that matches stored value? true
  // - has no email and stored value is missing? true
  // - has no email and stored value is ""? true
  // - otherwise? false
  // note: while request.auth.token.get("email", "") could also be used,
  //       the token should probably always have the "email" claim and
  //       throw an error when it doesn't.
  function emailMatches(resource) {
    return request.auth.token.email == resource.data.get("insensitiveEmail", "")
  }
    
  // Returns true if the auth uid matches the resource's uid 
  function uidMatchesResource(resource) {
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
        && request.auth.uid == resource.id; // <- this line could be removed because of request.auth.uid == userId check
  }

  // note spread out for clarity, will need flattening
  allow get: if request.auth != null
        && request.auth.uid == userId
        && (
          resource == null // permit read when document does not exist
          || (
            uidMatchesResource(resource) // or when the uid & email match in existing document
            && emailMatches(resource)
          )
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not get:

> Missing or Insufficient Permissions.

Even if the document doesn't exist. However, the following rule:

```
// Returns true if the auth uid matches the resource's uid 
function uidMatchesResource(resource) {
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid && request.auth.uid == resource.id;
}
```

Cannot be evaluated as `true` if the document doesn't exist and therefore the Firebase servers will reject the operation and you'll indeed get a "Missing or Insufficient Permissions" when you set a listener on the non-existing document.

So in your case, instead of directly checking the UID, you should use [`exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.exists) to check if the document exists.

Comment: Often faster and simpler to just check if `resource` is `null` or not instead of using `exists()` if being used on the same document as the one the rule is protecting. `resource` is `null` when the target document does not exist.

Comment: Yes, the OP can also check the `resource` object against nullity. Thanks, @samthecodingman